# Error: redux-persist persist all reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using `redux-persist` in my project to save a user token in the `asycnStorage`, but I have a problem. `redux-persist` persist all the reducers.

```
// config
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
// reducers
import ApiTokenReducer from './reducers/ApiTokenReducer';
import CartReducer from './reducers/CartReducer';;
import profileReducer from './reducers/ProfileReducer';
import dishesReducer from './reducers/addDishesReducer';
import FinalizeOrderReducer from './reducers/FinalizeOrderReducer';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'USER_TOKEN',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whiteList: ['Token'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  Token: ApiTokenReducer,
  cart: CartReducer,
  profile: profileReducer,
  dishes: dishesReducer,
  finalizeOrder: FinalizeOrderReducer,
});

// export default rootReducer;
export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Any clue what's the problem or maybe the solution?

Comment: it's seems fine as you have already provided whiteList which means only Token Reducer will be persisted.

Comment: are you doing Nested Persists?

Comment: @Utonium what do you mean by Nested Persists?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Looks fine to me too. Can you clear local storage and try again?
Maybe it's still there from a previous attempt?